# cbind a vector multiple times in R

Tags: r

I have a vector I would like to repeat n times using the vector as columns in the new matrix

i.e I have a vector

```
vec <- c(266, 130, 86, 69, 56, 39, 30, 44, 33, 43)
vec
[1] 266 130  86  69  56  39  30  44  33  43
```

I would like to produce n times

```
vec1 vec1
266  266
130  130
86   86
69   69
56   56
39   39
30   30
44   44  
33   33
43   43  .....
```

I am not entirely familiar with do.call but would you use that function to achieve this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

R recycles vectors when you create a matrix, so you can use:

```
matrix( vec , length(vec) , n )
```

where `n` is the number of columns/repetitions.

Answer (score 3):

Another obvious alternative here is to use `replicate` (though `matrix` should be more efficient):

```
> vec <- scan()
1: 266 130  86  69  56  39  30  44  33  43
11: 
Read 10 items
> replicate(5, vec)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]  266  266  266  266  266
 [2,]  130  130  130  130  130
 [3,]   86   86   86   86   86
 [4,]   69   69   69   69   69
 [5,]   56   56   56   56   56
 [6,]   39   39   39   39   39
 [7,]   30   30   30   30   30
 [8,]   44   44   44   44   44
 [9,]   33   33   33   33   33
[10,]   43   43   43   43   43
```

Or, you could take a more cryptic (but possibly faster) approach like:

```
`dim<-`(rep(vec, 5), c(length(vec), 5))
```